# How can i add a method that will count the time the program is running?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Like a digital clock with hours minutes seconds and milliseconds 00:00:00:00
This is a class i have now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Capture.Hook
{
    public class FramesPerSecond
    {
        int _frames = 0;
        int _lastTickCount = 0;
        float _lastFrameRate = 0;

        public void Frame()
        {
            _frames++;
            if (Math.Abs(Environment.TickCount - _lastTickCount) > 1000)
            {
                _lastFrameRate = (float)_frames * 1000 / Math.Abs(Environment.TickCount - _lastTickCount);
                _lastTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
                _frames = 0;
            }
        }

        public float GetFPS()
        {
            return _lastFrameRate;
        }
    }
}
```

And i use it like this in another class:

```
if (this.FPS.GetFPS() >= 1)
                        {
                            font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} fps", this.FPS.GetFPS()), 5, 5, SharpDX.Color.Red);
                            font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} fps", this.FPS.GetFPS()), 5, 5, SharpDX.Color.Red);
                        }
```

What i want is that the second line:

```
font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} fps", this.FPS.GetFPS()), 5, 5, SharpDX.Color.Red);
```

To be display under the first line and will show the time clock.
Maybe i can add the method that show the time in this class and not in the FramesPerSecond class.

How can i make the method and how to display it using the font.DrawText ?

What i tried so far in the FramesPerSecond class i added:

```
static DateTime _startTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Then added:

```
public static TimeSpan RunTime
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Now - _startTime;
            }
        }
```

Then in the other class to use it i added:

```
string timeRunning = FramesPerSecond.RunTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ff");
```

And i'm getting exception on this line: string timeRunning = FramesPerSecond.RunTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ff");

```
Error: Error in InitialiseHook: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.FormatCustomized(TimeSpan value, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi)
   at System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.Format(TimeSpan value, String format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
   at System.TimeSpan.ToString(String format)
```

Comment: Is the "time clock" the current system time, the game running time, some kind of task elapsed time, etc?

Comment: Ron the "time clock" is the game running time. Since the game is in directx fullscreen mode i should use it the same with the font drawtext and the GetFPS same idea.  What i need is just a timer or something like that and to display it just like i display the GetFPS with the font.DrawText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FramesPerSecond
{
    int _frames = 0;
    int _lastTickCount = 0;
    float _lastFrameRate = 0;
    DateTime _startTime = DateTime.Now;

    public Timespan RunTime
    {
        get
        {
             return DateTime.Now - _startTime;
        }
     }

    public void Frame()
    {
        _frames++;
        if (Math.Abs(Environment.TickCount - _lastTickCount) > 1000)
        {
            _lastFrameRate = (float)_frames * 1000 / Math.Abs(Environment.TickCount - _lastTickCount);
            _lastTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
            _frames = 0;
        }
    }

    public float GetFPS()
    {
        return _lastFrameRate;
    }
}
```

Just add a DateTime and track between calls, to use it, you just need to use something like this:

```
string timeRunning = FPS.RunTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:ff");
```

And then draw that out wherever you want.

Comment: Ron i'm getting exception error on the line: string timeRunning = FramesPerSecond.RunTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ff"); the exception is: Error: Error in InitialiseHook: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.FormatCustomized(TimeSpan value, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi)
   at System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.Format(TimeSpan value, String format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
   at System.TimeSpan.ToString(String format)
   at Capture.Hook.DXHookD3D9..ctor(CaptureInterface ssInterface)

Comment: Try it without the "hh:mm:ss:ff" in there, it shouldn't complain but thats pretty much the default ToString implementation. just use `FPS.RunTime.ToString()`

Comment: You might have to escape the :'s, this should work too: `FPS.RunTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:ff");` Sorry about that, I'll edit the post.

Comment: Ron it's working now. Just one small question please how do i make that the line i added now that i draw the text font.DrawText with the StringFormat String.Format("{0:N0} time running " how do i make that it will be display in a new line with a space between them since i have two lines of font.DrawText and they are on on the other and i need to add \r or \n

Comment: @user1196715 I'm just guessing here because I can't bring up the SharpDx documentation, but I think the 5,5 in the DrawString call is the location? You need to change the second one to reposition it below the first one by increasing the Y value (which is probably the second "5").

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to display a continually updating text with an incremental timer noting time elapsed, the way I've found that works best for me is to add a `Timer` Windows Form class to your form, start a `Stopwatch` (using `System.Diagnostics`), and attach a method to the timer `Tick` event to update the label or whatever the text for the clock is held in.

```
// Don't forget the using in your imports and such
using System.Diagnostics;

Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

public void CheckTime()
{
    label1.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\:ff");
}

public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckTime();
}
```

By default, I believe the Timer has an interval of 100. If you want it to update more more frequently than that I'd recommend 10.

`timer1.Interval = 10;`